# Need to update /etc/hosts every time I connect to network because of dynamic IP

Tags: networking, dhcp

Every time I connect to the network at work my device gets a new IP address which makes it `/etc/hosts/` invalid and my hostname becomes unreachable.

I was looking for a way to set `/etc/hosts` automatically every time I reconnect and I came across [dhclient-scrip](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/en/man8/dhclient-script.8.html).

I am pretty new to Ubuntu world and honestly I got lost through all this :)

All I need is just to update the IP of my local hostname when my local IP changes.

Thanks
**EDIT:**
here is my `/etc/hosts`

> 128.141.239.50 mtahawi.comp.com mtahawi
>   127.0.0.1 localhost
>   127.0.1.1 mtahawi

so the problem is: the IP I am mapping to my hostname `mtahawi.comp.com` is changing when I reconnect.
I forgot to say I am using a WiFi.

Comment: Why not tackle it the other way round and have your work network administrator assign a static IP address to your device?

Comment: What in your `/etc/hosts` invalidates it when _your_ machine gets a new IP address? Sounds a bit suspicious to me. Can you post it here?

Comment: @ClassStacker: in a minute

Comment: And why does _your_ machine need to know its fully qualified name to find itself? why can't you have the full name as an alias for `localhost`?

Answer (score 0):

Why do it the hard way?

Bind your MAC to an ip or use address reservation.  Every server should have a static ip for more than just the reason you have.